# how to check RAM for a host in marklogic?

Tags: marklogic

Is there a way we can check the  RAM and total disk size of Marklogic host?

I tried looking at the admin console page but I only see free space details for each forest.
I want the total RAM and total disk size of the markogic host.

Answer (score 0):

For memory utilization, which will fluctuate depending upon activities, it is logged on a regular basis in the ErrorLog.txt and can be obtained from [`xdmp:host-status()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/hosts@view=status) method and the Manage API host status [/manage/v2/hosts?view=status (GET)](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/hosts@view=status).

Do note that MarkLogic makes use of memory mapped files for things such as range indexes, so even when it looks as if there is free memory available, it may be needed for OS file/buffer cache in order to operate efficiently. Read more about the allocation of memory and utilization in this knowledgebase article:

https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/memory-consumption-logging-and-status

For disk size, you can see that displayed in the [Monitoring Dashboard](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/monitoring/dashboard#id_60621) on the Disk Space tab:
[image: MarkLogic Monitoring Dashboard Disk Space]

and that information is available from the Manage API [/manage/v2/forests?view=storage (GET)](https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/GET/manage/v2/forests@view=storage) and [`xdmp:forest-status()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:forest-status) method.